# Rollbar 413 when using Node, but not when using curl

Tags: node.js, curl, rollbar

I'm trying to upload the sourcemap to Rollbar. Using `curl` this works fine:

```
curl https://api.rollbar.com/api/1/sourcemap \
        -F access_token=${ACCESS_TOKEN} \
        -F version=${VERSION} \
        -F minified_url=${1} \
        -F source_map=@${SOURCE_MAP_PATH}
```

However, using a Node app, I get `Error: Request failed with status code 413`:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const FormData = require('form-data');
const axios = require('axios');

const stream = fs.createReadStream('/path/to/sourcemap');
const config = {
  filename: 'sourcemap',
  contentType: 'application/json',
}

const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('access_token', 'the-token');
formData.append('version', '1.2.3');
formData.append('minified_url', 'https://example.com/1.2.3/minified.js');
formData.append('source_map', stream, config);

axios.post('https://api.rollbar.com/api/1/sourcemap', formData, {
  headers: formData.getHeaders(),
});
```

These are both the exact same file. Not sure why the Node version doesn't work.

**Edit**

Interesting, if I spawn a `curl` command then it works:

```
const execaArgs = [
    'https://api.rollbar.com/api/1/sourcemap',
    '-F',
    'access_token=abc',
    '-F',
    'version=1.2.3',
    '-F',
    'minified_url='https://example.com/1.2.3/minified.js',
    '-F',
    `source_map=@${filePath}`
  ]
  const {stdout, stderr} = await execa('curl', execaArgs);
```

So does `fetch`:

```
fetch('https://api.rollbar.com/api/1/sourcemap', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData
  })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => console.log(json));
```

Comment: You can use the following tool to convert and get the code:

https://curl.trillworks.com/#node

They support:

Node.js
Python
PHP

Comment: Doesn't work for multipart curl

Answer (score 0):

### As you mentioned

> if I spawn a curl command then it works
>
> So does fetch
>
> But not in Axios

---

`HTTP 413` is a "Payload too large" from your **server**, but as it works fine with fetch I guess it's not caused by the server.

You can try
https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios#request-config

```
axios({
url: '',
method: 'post',
data: {}
headers: {}
})
```

And keep us updated .

Comment: If it's still not working we need to dig more in Axios documentation, and may open a new issue for this scenario.

Comment: Using `axios({})` also throws the same error. I'm asking Rollbar to see what they say; I'll keep you updated.